# How to get char element LIKE Array in sql?

Tags: macros

i need your help how to getting char element LIKE Array in SQL.

This is my program :

```
Char code[5]
ex. code = "LA 12"

result = RecipeQuery("SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE Name_Recipe LIKE '%(code)%';", n_records)
```

And it doesnt work.
value of result is nothing.

Any idea?

Thank guys.

Comment: This is not SQL code.  You have some application that is calling SQL.  And "doesn't work" is not helpful.  More description.

Comment: Which programming language is that? And which database product are you using?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE Name_Recipe LIKE '%" + code + "%';"`?

Comment: it's macro language.
it's has sql syntax.

i have a statement show a value.

result = RecipeQuery("SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE Name_Recipe=%(code);", n_records)


the value of result will show/match when the input same.

Comment: @BangBoneng "Macro" is not a language. Please tell in which program/application you use this code (specify it in your tags).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I think the tag `macros`  - even if discouraged - is better than `sql` in this case. Because this is definitely **not**  a "SQL question"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well, I removed the macro tag because this question doesn't meet the description of that tag. It eves says in its [info text](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) *"questions relating to other macro programming languages should not use this tag"* • But If you have a better idea how to tag this feel free.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: as I wrote: I think the `sql` tag is even worse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you use, but I think you need to get a form like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE Name_Recipe ARRAY[Name_Recipe] <@ ARRAY["L","A"," ","1","2"]
```

You can see this link : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Comment: it doesnt work.

it's macro language. it's has sql syntax. i have a statement show a value. result = RecipeQuery("SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE Name_Recipe=%(code);", n_records) the value of result will show/match when the input same